# Interpreter project "input" - Python-3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am still making my programming language in programming language project. Print is done, and I made input, but it doesn't work. This is my attempt to make input:

```
progress = []
command_libary = []
command_split = []
def split_command(command):
    command2 = command.split()
    for x in command2:
        command_split.extend(x)
    command_libary.extend(command)
def C05basic(command3):
    x = 0
    z = 0
    split_command(command3)
    if (command_split[z] == "p" and command_split[z + 1] == "r" and command_split[z + 2] == "i" and command_split[z + 3] == "n" and command_split[z + 4] == "t" and command_split[z + 5] == "("):
        if (command_split[z + 6] == '"' or command_split[z + 6] == "'" or command_split[z + 6] == "`"):
            for x in range(z + 7, len(command_split)):
                if ((command_split[x] == '"' or command_split[x] == "'" or command_split[x] == "`") and command_split[x + 1] == ')'):
                    break
                progress.extend(command_split[x])
            print ("".join(progress))
            z = z + 6 + len(progress)
            progress.pop()
    elif (command_split[z] == "i" and command_split[z + 1] == "n" and command_split[z + 2] == "p" and command_split[z + 3] == "u" and command_split[z + 4] == "t" and command_split[z + 5] == "("):
        if (command_split[z + 6] == '"' or command_split[z + 6] == "'" or command_split[z + 6] == "`"):
            for x in range(z + 7, len(command_split)):
                if ((command_split[x] == '"' or command_split[x] == "'" or command_split[x] == "`") and command_split[x + 1] == ')'):
                    break
                progress.extend(command_split[x])
            input ("".join(progress))
            z = z + 6 + len(progress)
            progress.pop()
    progress.pop()
    command_split.pop()    

C05basic("input('something')")
```

it gives me:

```
something #in input
```

but when I use:

```
C05basic("print('something')")
C05basic("input('something')")
```

it gives me:

```
something
somethisomething'input('something #Not written by command input (, but by print)
```

Idk why... What I doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably the call to `C05basic("print('something')")` causes changes to your global variables `progress` and `command_split`, and those changes stick around when you call `C05basic("input('something')")`. This is why it's generally discouraged to use mutable global variables: because it makes it much harder to reason about the behavior of isolated sections of your code without having to take into account every other part of your code. Perhaps you could redesign your code to use no globals. Hint: what if `split_command` returned a list instead of modifying an existing one?

Comment: I suggest you learn some debugging skills. Add extra print() statements to view values of the variable in your program. Alternatively, learn how to use a visual debugger such as the one in PyCharm.

Comment: I also suggest that you read about compiler theory. In particular, you need to learn what a lexical analyzer is and what a parser is.

Comment: Checking individual characters looks really bad. Learn about list slicing

Comment: Start here: https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANALYSIS**

You haven't specified what you *expect* from this.  However, I gather that you have some idea of parsing commands.  To follow what you're doing, I made a trivial debugging insertion near the top of `C05basic`:

```
def C05basic(command3):
    x = 0
    z = 0
    split_command(command3)
    print "TRACE command_split", command_split
    print "TRACE progress", progress
```

The output I get from your two cases:

1 command:

```
TRACE command_split ['i', 'n', 'p', 'u', 't', '(', "'", 's', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', "'", ')']
TRACE progress []
something
```

2 commands:

```
TRACE command_split ['p', 'r', 'i', 'n', 't', '(', "'", 't', 'h', 'i', 's', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'f', "'", ')']
TRACE progress []
thisstuff
TRACE command_split ['p', 'r', 'i', 'n', 't', '(', "'", 't', 'h', 'i', 's', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'f', "'", 'i', 'n', 'p', 'u', 't', '(', "'", 's', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', "'", ')']
TRACE progress ['t', 'h', 'i', 's', 's', 't', 'u']
thisstuthisstuff'input('something
```

Very briefly, you're not bothering to control your data lists and subscripts.  The result is that you truncate, concatenate, overlap, and generally mis-handle the second input.

**RECOMMENDATIONS**

Learn incremental programming.  Part of your problem here is that you coded far too much before you tested anything.  Instead, write a few lines, make sure they work, and only then add more.

Learn basic debugging.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Learn the basic capabilities of the new language before you dive in.  For instance, you've made this very hard to read because you haven't yet learned basic string operations.  For instance, your first large **if** statement can be greatly improved with a trivial string comparison, a slice against a constant:

```
if command_split[z: z+5] == "print":
```

Comparing character by character wastes a lot of time and visual space.